# Two way sms using IBM worklight without internet connection

Tags: sms, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-server

I have implemented two way SMS communication using IBM worklight V6.1 .But I wanted to know is it possible to send SMS without internet connection.Because I am not able to hit worklight server without internet connection

Comment: Are you testing with an actual SMS gateway? In that case, you would not need an internet connection from your mobile phone.

Comment: No I have downloaded SMS Gateway Ultimate app in mobile phone and am getting error in procedure failure that "Request timed out for http://ipAddress:portNo/projectName/apps/services/api/Test/android/query. Make sure the host is available to the application"

Answer (score 2):

If you are using SMS Gateway Ultimate app as the gateway then you would need internet connection (dataplan/wifi). This article might be of help

https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/worklight/entry/testing_worklight_push_notifications_over_sms?lang=en

Comment: One thing I wanted to ask.In our SMS enabled app,Worklight server is going to communicate with Back end system. So is it possible to achieve this without internet connection